# Getting a score to show in a java game constantly, g.drawString isn't working

Tags: java, scoring

I have been trying to get a score to display in my 2D java game constantly in the top left (while its being played) I created an int for the Score and linked it to some things that would give the player score. I then created a string of "Score: " + Score; And when I try to use g.drawString(ScoreDisplay, 10, 10); it tells me that i have to change the int and string to static. It will then have no errors and run fine, but when i get into the game, nothing is displaying. How can i fix this? is there a better way to do it?

```
public static int Score = 0;
public static String ScoreCount = "Score: " + Score;

public void displayScore(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString(Player.ScoreCount, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: I'm a huge newb at this, I don't understand what it is, it's for a college project and they are rushing us.

Comment: To display the score you can use a [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html).

Comment: Where is your `paint` or `paintComponent` method? `displayScore` willl do nothing on its own. Also as @PeterMmm suggested, why not just use a `JLabel` and `setText`?

Comment: It's all very well saying just do this, but I have no idea, I'm really stuck, I've tried JLabels before I couldn't get anything to display - is there a block of code that I can put in to get it to display? I've spent hours and hours on this and its just making my head hurt